# rewrite jsp style to normal jsp scriplet code

Tags: jsp

```
<jsp:root version="1.2" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:display="urn:jsptld:http://displaytag.sf.net">

<jsp:root>
```

hi how to rewrite above code using <% %>

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can, as there are no expression(s) in the statements.